# Next Button XPath Changes on Page #2, Won't Loop

Tags: python, selenium

I have a script that loops through a series of elements for titles, then clicks "next" to load the next series of elements to be scraped. The issue is the xpath of the "next" button changes on page 2 and quite possibly on page 3. I cannot use find by class or find by ID because there are more than one occurrence of those class/ID names. Once it cannot find the "next" button on the 2nd page the script errors out.

```
while True: 
    deal_title = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='dealTitle']/span")
    titles = []
    for title in deal_title:
        titles.append(title.text)

    deal_link = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row dealDetailContainer']/div/a[@id='dealTitle']")
    links = []
    for link in deal_link:
        links.append(link.get_attribute('href'))

    deal_image = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@id='dealImage']/div/div/div/img")
    images = []
    for image in deal_image:
        images.append(image.get_attribute('src'))

    deal_price = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='a-row priceBlock unitLineHeight']/span")
    prices = []
    for price in deal_price:
        prices.append(price.text)

    try:
        #clicks next button - this is the xpath for the page 1 button
        browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-declarative']/div[2]/ul/li[@class='a-last']/a").click()
    except NoSuchElementException:
    break
```

Below is the xpath for the next button on page 2:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-declarative']/div[1]/ul/li[@class='a-last']/a").click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to replace

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-declarative']/div[2]/ul/li[@class='a-last']/a").click()
```

with

```
browser.find_element_by_link_text("Next→").click()
```

Comment: can you see my latest question. Was hoping you could answer it for me? Btw, I have a friend in Kiev.

Answer (score 0):

You could conjoin them together
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='a-declarative']/div[2]/ul/li[@class='a-last']/a|//span[@class='a-declarative']/div[1]/ul/li[@class='a-last']/a
").click()
 Or you could write a more generic xpath
//li[@class='a-last']/a